# Persist mongodb data in docker volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-volume

I am new to docker and I am trying to persist the data I insert in my mongodb container. After a few google searches I found out that I need to create a volume where the container data will be persisted.

So I run this command:

```bash
docker run --rm -p 27017:27017 -v $(pwd):/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb mongo
```

It creates successfully a container and a volume with this target:

```bash
/data/configdb              # dont know what is this
/data/db                    # dont know what is this either
/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb   # this is my local path to the mongodb data
```

Then I create some data in the mongo container:

```bash
use mycollection
db.users.insert({ id: 1 }) # WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

All good at this point. But when I delete the container and run it again the data is no longer there.

Am I missing something? All tips/tricks are appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: The second `docker run -v` path is the path inside the container and it looks like it needs to be `/data/db` here or else the database won't notice it.

Comment: I already tried that one `docker run --rm -p 27017:27017 -v $(pwd):/data/db mongo`, but It shows an error like this `find: '/data/db/.Trash': Operation not permitted`

Comment: The current directory `$(pwd)` might have some extraneous content in it that makes it unusable as the MongoDB data store.

Comment: That's correct! when replacing `$(pwd)` with my actual mongodb data directory it worked! `docker run --rm -p 27017:27017 -v /path/to/mongodbdata:/data/db mongo`